# How to show only certain items

Tags: php

The code below gets all domains from a database table called "url_domain" in my database and outputs them in a dropdown list that users can use to select which domain to use from.

What I want when this code is run is that instead of it showing all available domains in the list it should only show the domains where in the database `premium_only` is set to 1 and 6, nothing else should be shown in the list.

**If I try the following**
If I try to use the following code the only domains with premium_only set to 1 shows up when I run it not both 1 and 6, why?

```
if(($shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] != '1') && ($shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] != '6'))
{
continue;
}
```

**Other stuff**:

Database layout:

```
Table: url_domain

id | domain           | premium_only | status  | date_created
---+------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------
1  | exaple.com       | 1            | enabled | 2020-03-02 08:13:00
2  | exaple2.com      | 0            | enabled | 2021-03-02 08:13:00
3  | exaple2.org      | 0            | enabled | 2021-03-02 08:13:00
4  | text.exaple2.se  | 6            | enabled | 2021-03-02 08:13:00
```

PHP code:

```
<div>
    <label for="shortUrlDomain"><?php echo t("short_url_domain", "Short Url Domain"); ?>:</label>
    <select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
        <?php
        foreach ($shortUrlDomains AS $k => $shortUrlDomain)
        {
            echo '<option value="' . (int) $k . '"';
            // selected option
            if ($k == (int) $_REQUEST['shortUrlDomain']) {
                echo ' SELECTED';
            }
            echo '>';
            echo $shortUrlDomain['domain'];
            if($disabled == true) {
                echo ' ('.safeOutputToScreen(t('unavailable', 'unavailable')).')';
            }
            '</option>';
        }
        echo '</optgroup>';
    ?>
    </select>
</div>

// get base urls
$shortUrlDomains = getShortUrlDomains();

static function getShortUrlDomain($domainId)
{
    // get base urls
    $shortUrlDomains = getShortUrlDomains();
    
    if(!isset($shortUrlDomains[$domainId]))
    {
        return _CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL.'://'._CONFIG_SITE_FULL_URL;
    }
    
    return _CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL.'://'.$shortUrlDomains[$domainId]['domain'];
}
```

Comment: If you have SQL specifically to retrieve these records, you could add `and premium_only in (1,6)` to the where clause.

Comment: You missed ```<optgroup>```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to select the only wanted fields in SQL but if you can't or you want to keep all the results for next use in the script, you can check, in the loop if the result match with values like this :

```
   if ( in_array( $shortUrlDomain['premium_only'], [1,6] ) ) {
     //result is in array [1,6] so you can write your select options here
   ....
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  Just posting code does not help the author please explain why your code helps.